# Understanding matplotlib xticks syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am reading a book and I came across this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.title("Web traffic over the last month")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Hits/hour")
plt.xticks([w*7*24 for w in range(10)], 
  ['week %i'%w for w in range(10)])
plt.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

For context, `x` is an array of integers corresponding to an hour.  `y` is an array of "hits" (from users to a website) in that particular hour.

I understand that the code accumulates all the hours so that it can display them in a week, **but could someone please explain what these functions do?  My goal is to understand all the syntax of this line:**

```
plt.xticks([w*7*24 for w in range(10)], 
  ['week %i'%w for w in range(10)])
```

Specifically:

- What is `range`?

This is what gets generated:
[image]

Here is sample data for additional context:

```
1   2272
2   nan
3   1386
4   1365
5   1488
6   1337
7   1883
8   2283
9   1335
10  1025
11  1139
12  1477
13  1203
14  1311
15  1299
16  1494
17  1159
18  1365
19  1272
20  1246
21  1071
22  1876
23  nan
24  1410
25  925
26  1533
27  2104
28  2113
29  1993
30  1045
```

Comment: My advice to understand range:
Open python and write: range(7)
When you see the result, write: range(4,8)
And when you are done write: range(3,11,2)

Comment: For the other stuff, this is called a comprehension list. I think the purists will forgive me if this is not 100% accurate, but it is basically a compact way of writing loops. You can google it, it is very common, useful and neat. In order to understand them you can do:
[w*2 for w in range(10)]   and   [w*2 for w in range(10) if w < 4]

Comment: @Jblasco - we forgive you, but it is a "list comprehension".

Comment: @Robᵩ I stand corrected... Funny enough I had written it correctly, then changed it to the wrong order. I need more coffee. Thanks!

Comment: @Jblasco Can you please write those comments as the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to understand range, open python and write in sequence the following commands:

```
 range(7) 
 range(4,8) 
 range(3,11,2)
```

For the list comprehensions within the plt.xticks, they are basically a compact way of writing loops. They are very common, useful and neat. In order to understand them:

```
 [w*2 for w in range(10)] 
 [w*2 for w in range(10) if w < 4]
```

Finally, for the command plt.xticks itself you can check http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks for a very brief explanation with simple examples.

Answer (score 12):

range is a function in `python2` which makes a list for the argument given to it:

```
range(5) -> [0,1,2,3,4]
range(1,5) -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

in general `range(lower_index, upper_index+1)` will generate a list equivalent to
`[ lower_index, upper_index]` in `python2`,

you can use `xrange` for better performance ( as it's uses lazy evaluation, calculating when it is needed) or `range` in `python3` will do the work as `xrange` in `python2`.

now for the line:

```
plt.xticks([w*24*7 for w in range(10)],['week %i'%w for w in range(10)])
```

actually `xticks` is the interval for your x axis ticks or measurement, so as your level of measurement is in `hours` so it is better to tick for each hour in a week (i.e. `7 days * 24 hours`) for the week's in the data set,
and the second list comprehension put's the `label's` for that one week interval`( week 0, week 1 .....)`,

one point to notice is that actually the data set you have used from the book have 748 rows so approximately (748/(24*7)) = 4.45 weeks ,,

so you really can plot the graph using range(5),
the reason the output plot is scaled to week0 - week4 is because of the line
`plt.autoscale(tight=True)`,
well without `plt.autoscale` the plot would have shown something like this.[image: wihtout plt.autoscale(tight=True) and plt.grid()]

hope it helps.