# plt.hist() with extremes as "minor than x", "grater than y"

Tags: python, matplotlib, bins

Here is the example:

```
v = np.random.randint(low=-15,high=15,size=20)
plt.hist(v,bins=[-10,-5,0,5,10])
plt.show()
```

now, I would like to set the bins like ["minor than -10", -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, "greater than 10"].

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

use plt.xticks() will help you.

Refer the below links

[https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html][1]

[[Understanding matplotlib xticks syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427188/understanding-matplotlib-xticks-syntax][1])

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to add 'greater or less than'.  You can change the values (v) if > 10 or < -10 then manually add the string '>' or '<' at the end of bins.

```
np.random.seed(123)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
v = np.random.randint(low=-15,high=15,size=20)
v_plot = [15 if i > 10 else i for i in v]
v_plot = [-15 if i < -10 else i for i in v_plot]
bins = np.arange(-15,20,5)
plt.hist(np.clip(v_plot, bins[0], bins[-1]),bins=bins)
xlabels = bins[1:].astype(str)
xlabels[-1] = '>' + xlabels[-2] 
xlabels[0]  = '< ' + xlabels[0] 
N_labels = len(xlabels)
plt.xlim([-15, 15])
plt.xticks(5*np.arange(N_labels)-12.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels) 
plt.title('Sample: Greater and less than')    
plt.show()
```

[image]